# Android Studio: How do I find where Gradle has been installed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have installed `Android Studio` but would like to use `Gradle` to build a simple "hello world" `Java` application that I have created outside of AS.

I have added the `java plugin` to my `build.gradle` file and ran `"gradle build" to try and build the .java file.

However, I am getting the error: `"Gradle is not recognised as an internal or external command"`

Do I need to install a *separate* version of Gradle, not bundled with AS to be able to build a `java` project?

Comment: i would have thought copying and paste the the java plugin to your projects libs folder would work, but i maybe wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to install a separate version of Gradle, not bundled with AS to be able to build a java project?

More or less.

There are two ways of using Gradle:

- Download and install it, like you would most other development tools
- Have a project set up for the Gradle Wrapper (`gradlew` and `gradlew.bat` files in the project root, plus the `gradle/` directory containing the Wrapper JAR and `properties` file)

That latter approach will download a *private* copy of Gradle for this particular project, into the project's `.gradle/` directory. This way, different projects can use different versions of Gradle without conflict.

Android Studio takes the latter approach; you can see the files that I mentioned in a newly-created Android Studio project, for example. For your own Java project, I'd do whatever is natural for your IDE that you plan on using for that project.

Comment: Thank you, I was just learning about gradlew as you wrote that! Basically, I am using AS for all my android dev but I am running through gradle tutorials and want to learn using gradle on the cmd line, would you reccomend downloading a seperate version of gradle to do so?

Comment: @rni902: I use a standalone copy of Gradle, mostly because the Gradle Wrapper is a bit risky from a security standpoint IMHO. That being said, there's nothing stopping you from copying the files I mentioned from an AS project to a regular Java project and using the Gradle Wrapper if you want.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will download a seperate gradle version for my gradle/java tutorials. From my understanding gradlew basically ensures that the same version of gradle is always used for building a project, i.e. so that everyone is using the same version of the build script?

Comment: @rni902: Yes. And as I said in my answer, the copy of Gradle is private to the project. So, if you're like me, and you have hundreds of Android Studio projects, they all do not have to be using the same version of Gradle. OTOH, if you're like me, and you have hundreds of Android Studio projects, you have a *lot* of private copies of the Gradle binaries. :-)